# laravel "error when sending email fwrite(): send of 18 bytes failed with errno=10054"

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel I got this error when I send emails

fwrite(): send of 18 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
it was working normally

this is my configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp    
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com   
MAIL_PORT=587      
MAIL_USERNAME=givkom@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=123456789
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

`Mail::to($request->email)->send(new DonorMail());`

Comment: add some more code...sending email section and sending the request part

Answer (score 1):

change `.env` file like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS(GMAIL)
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

The `MAIL_USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` should be replaced with your Gmail Email address and Password respectively.
Since we are using Gmail `SMTP`, we need to change some security settings on our Google account, to give access to less secured applications.

### Configure your Google Account

Login to your Google Email Account and click on Google Account Button.

Once you are on My Account Page then click on Security and scroll down to the bottom and you will find ‘[Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)’ settings. Click on the radio button to set it ON.